How to print out all printable ASCII strings contained in binary data?
How can I print out all printable ASCII strings
(e.g., longer than four chars) contained in a binary file?

man strings ...

By including a solution (strings) in the question, you made it look like a non-question; and you made the answer that actually gave you the right tool look like a trivial echo of what's in the question. I have reverted your edit.

This question is similar to: pulling strings out of mixed file of strings and binary. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

ASCII is a character set which assigns characters for each byte value from 0 to 127. Out of those, 33 (corresponding to byte values 0 to 31 and 127) are control characters (some of which (\n, \t) often used in text, also \r for Microsoft text, more rarely \b for bold/underline handling in some applications, \e for graphic rendition escape sequences), and the rest printable (one of which (space on byte value 32) non-graphical).
So if it's really about finding strings of 4 ASCII characters or more, then that could be a matter of finding sequences of 4 or more bytes in the 0-127 range, which you could do with perl with:
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /[\0-\177]{4,}/g'

(here printed newline delimited (newline being in ASCII)).
Now in a given binary file, it's not because bytes have values between 0 and 127 that they were intended to be ASCII encoded text. In particular, byte 0 which represents the ASCII NUL control character is rarely found in text, so much so that the presence of that byte value is often a clear indicator that the file contains binary data rather than text.
So, removing it from the list along with control characters other than newline and maybe tab, may be more likely to give you sequences of bytes intended to be ASCII character strings.
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print for /[\t\n\40-\176]{4,}/g'

(to which you might want to add \e, \10 (BS, \b is for something different in perl)).
Note that those control characters (\t, \n, \e, \b) will be printed as-is to the terminal if you don't redirect it to a file.
You could do:
perl -MJSON::PP -l -0777 -ne 'print encode_json$_ for /[\10\t\n\e\40-\176]{4,}/g'

To print a JSON string representation of those strings. For instance, on the contents of /bin/ls on my system, that would show things like:
"sha384sum"
"sha512sum"
"\n%s online help: <%s>\n"
"GNU coreutils"
"Full documentation <%s%s>\n"
"full-iso"

Instead of:
sha384sum
sha512sum

%s online help: <%s>

GNU coreutils
Full documentation <%s%s>

full-iso

When sent to a terminal device, the newline aka linefeed control character (represented as \n in a JSON string) is typically translated to the carriage-return+newline sequence of control characters, the first of which moves the cursor to the start of the line (returns the carriage) and the second moves it one row down (feeds a line) in virtually all terminals. That's how Unix makes sure newline is represented there as the line delimiter it is meant to be.

The command strings is what you’re looking for
to see all ASCII strings in a binary file.
